# Google Sheets Data Validation

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I have a google sheet and I'm trying to validate my data properly. I need to input a value in Column G.

Conditions:

1. If column F is B2 to P3, the Quantity must be less than the B2 quantity.

2. If Column F is P3 to B2, the quantity must be less than the P3 quantity.

Attached is the google sheet. I'd really appreciate the help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z03XsplMyn3RMplxZoEizjfjB7Vr0ZEvrDLW6wQRJh8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the data validation rule based on condition of one column with different category of value from different column can be solved by using a helper column within the sheet or other sheet:

**First**, create a `If statement with arrayformula` (within current sheet or other reference sheet)

```
=arrayformula(IF(F2:F="B2 to P3",I2:I,H2:H))
```

[image]

**Second**, create the data validation rule based on the value of the `Helper value` as following then it is working as per your expectation:

[image]